# Literal blank space in URL sent from GET request in PHP

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, space, literals

Howdie,

being a noob i've tried to solve this on on my own but no result so far

after creating this link in PHP:

```
<a href ="edit_subject.php?subject=
                <?php echo $current_subject["id"]; ?>">Edit Subject</a>
```

the URL in Firefox shows a literal blank space in the browser like this:

```
edit_subject.php?subject=                1
```

everything works as it should but this really stumps me

Comment: Try this `a href ="edit_subject.php?subject=<?=$current_subject['id'];?>">Edit Subject</a>`

Answer (score 4):

Remove White space from the anchor tag

`<a href ="edit_subject.php?subject=<?php echo $current_subject["id"]; ?>">Edit Subject</a>`

White-space in the anchor tag consider as a URL parameter and it will shows like that. So try after removing it

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i only corrected the whitespace between the PHP tags which is allowed, now i see the space between = and `<?php`